# How do you bind parameters when using Doctrine's EntityRepository::matching() method with a Criteria object?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, sql-injection

I'm trying to use `Criteria` objects and the `EntityRepository::matching()` method to query my db:

```
$criteria = new Criteria();
$criteria->where(Criteria::expr()->eq('applied', false))
         ->andWhere(Criteria::expr()->eq('cancelled', false))
         ->andWhere(Criteria::expr()->eq('identifier', $identifier)) // danger Here

        ;

$results = $this->matching($criteria);
```

Problem is, one of the criteria parameters may come from the end-user (`$identifier`, specifically).

But `Criteria` and `matching(Criteria)` do not seem to allow to set and bind parameters.

How do I do perform these queries safely? Are parameters bound automatically for any query peformed with `EntityRepository::matching()`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `expr()->literal($identifier)` for this, it makes sure the parameter is properly escaped.